# Why is my Rebus handler being called multiple times for a single Azure Service Bus message?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, rebus

I'm using Rebus to send a message to an Azure Service Bus queue. For each message, my consumer's handler method seems to get called multiple times. `Received.` is written to 9 separate log files.

Producer:

```
await _bus.Advanced.Routing.Send("some-queue", new SomeMessage());
```

Consumer:

```
public class SomeMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<SomeMessage>
{
    public async Task Handle(SomeMessage message)
    {
        _logger.Information("Received.");

        await SomeApiCall();
    }
}
```

Consumer configuration:

```
builder.RegisterRebus((configurer, context) => configurer
    .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus("Endpoint=<redcated>;SharedAccessKeyName=<redacted>;SharedAccessKey=<redacted>", "some-queue")));
```

Comment: I see you figured it out, but why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @mookid8000 The handler is still being called multiple times even with exception handling. It's less than before, but it still runs at least twice on every message.

Comment: ok – in that case, I suspect that your IoC container is for some reason returning two handler instances every time Rebus resolves message handlers for the incoming message – could you maybe check your container registrations?

Comment: @mookid8000 Not sure why I thought it wasn't the exceptions, but I haven't had any more issues since getting rid of them. I'll undelete my answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method was throwing an unhandled exception. Rebus was trying to re-process it since it was erroring out.

Adding exception handling allowed the method to finish. Now the handler is only called one time as expected.